# Height of a view, that's inside of a card view, from the bottom of the screen? (Moving view above the keyboard when it opens)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, keyboard, snapkit

I have a rather complex situation. It has to do with moving a view above the keyboard. I have a chat view, much like the one Apple's Messages app. However, it's inside of a card that does not fill the entire screen. Above and below that card are a navigation bar and a tab bar.

Now, I want to move the editable UITextView (where the user composes their message) above the keyboard when they tap on it. I do have the height of the keyboard (using NotificationCenter Observer), but I need to subtract it from the height of the textview (inside of the card) from the height of the keyboard to calculate how much distance I should offset the textview by. A picture would probably help:

[image]

Here is my view stack:
View -> Card view -> ScrollView (that contains messages list tableview and chat tableview) -> TextBox View (that contains the UITextView, Send Button, etc.)

Is this doable? Is there a better way of doing this? I'm stuck and am pretty new at manipulating views in regards to the keyboard.

Here are scraps of code I have so far:

```html
    fileprivate var keyboardHeight = CGFloat()
    
    @objc fileprivate func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            let keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height
            self.keyboardHeight = keyboardHeight
        }
    }
    
    fileprivate func moveTextView(textView: UITextView, moveDistance: Int, up: Bool) {
        let moveDuration = 0.3
        let movement = CGFloat(up ? moveDistance : -moveDistance)
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: moveDuration) {
            self.snp.updateConstraints({ (make) in
                make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(movement)
            })
            
            self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
        
    }
```

```html
extension TextBarView: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        moveTextView(textView: textView, moveDistance: -200, up: true)
    }
    
    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        moveTextView(textView: textView, moveDistance: -200, up: false)
    }
    
    func textViewShouldEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

I am using SnapKit for autolayout.

(If you got through this entire post, thank you!)

Comment: There are notifications which tell you when the keyboard will show and hide. You should be using that instead of doing it in the text field delegates. Try googling "keyboard handling swift"

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I'll look into that.